# Can Git track an ancestor branch as well as its own branch?

Tags: git, git-track

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I've been searching for an hour+ and can't get a clear answer.

What I'd like to do is this:

- Checkout a remote branch `git checkout origin/feature`
- Make a local branch based off that branch `git checkout -b feature_my_tweak`
- So now I have a local copy of `feature` called `feature_my_tweak` that I can play around with
- Make some changes and `commit -m "added my tweak"` so now my local `feature_my_tweak` has diverged from `feature`
- Now do a `git push --set-upstream origin feature_my_tweak` to push my local branch to the remote server
- Now a workmate pushes a change to `feature` on the remote server

At this point, I would like to be able to `git pull` and have git see that there was a change to `feature` and pull it (fetch/merge) into my local `feature_my_tweak` branch.  Is there a way to do that automatically?  Or do I have to do a manually `git merge feature` to get all the changes from that branch to my local `feature_my_tweaks` branch?  I guess I thought there was a way to have one branch track another.

Another part of this is that I'd still like to be able to make local changes to `feature_my_tweaks` and still be able to `git push` and have that only push up to the remote `origin/feature_my_tweak` branch and not pollute the `origin/feature` branch.

Is there a way to do all that?  From what I can read, it seems that if any branch_A is tracking a remote branch_B, any pushes will go to branch_B, which is what I don't want.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The short version of the answer boils down to *no, but it doesn't matter, don't worry about it and just do it manually; it's easy*.  If you have one particular branch that you do this with often, write a script or a Git alias to do it.

#### Medium

To do this manually, for your branch *B* where you want to know if there's new stuff on `origin/feature`, vs your own branch `feature_my_tweaks` with upstream set to `origin/feature_my_tweaks`, just run:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right feature_my_tweaks...origin/feature
```

This prints out two numbers.  The number on the left is the number of commits that you have on `feature_my_tweaks` that are not part of your `origin/feature`.  The number on the right is the number of commits that are on your `origin/feature` that are not on your `feature_my_tweaks`.

If the second number is not zero, and you want to, you can now run `git checkout feature_my_tweaks; git rebase origin/feature` or `git checkout feature_my_tweaks; git merge origin/feature`.

Whether and when to use `git rebase` is up to you, but after rebasing, you will need to `git push --force origin feature_my_tweaks` (or `git push --force-with-lease origin feature_my_tweaks`) to get the Git over at `origin` to discard the old commits that your `git rebase` discarded when it copied your commits to new-and-improved commits.

#### Long

Probably the biggest problem here is terminology.  What does the word *tracking* mean to you?  Git uses this one word in at least three different ways,<sup>1</sup> so at most one of them can match up with the one you're thinking of.  (Possibly none of them match exactly, depending on what you're thinking happens here.)

Regardless of which word(s) you use, here is the right way to think about this:

- What matters are *commits*.  Each commit has a unique hash ID.  Every Git everywhere—every clone of this repository—uses *that* hash ID for that commit.  If you have a commit with *that* hash ID, it's the same commit.  If you don't, you don't have that commit.
- *Names* in Git take a bunch of forms.  Each name holds one hash ID—just one!

  The three forms that you use are:

  - *Branch names:* `master`, `develop`, `feature` or `feature/one`, and so on.  These are yours, to do with as you will.  (You'll probably *want* yours to match up with other peoples' names, though, at least at various times.)
  - *Tag names:* `v2.1` and so on.  While yours are yours, your Git will try to *share* them with other Git repositories: if your Git sees that theirs has a `v2.1` and you don't, your Git is likely to copy theirs to yours.
  - *Remote-tracking names:* `origin/master`, `origin/feature`, and so on.  Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names* and some people shorten that to *remote-tracking branch*, but they're not quite like *branch* names.  Your Git slaves these to some other Git's branch names.  You have your Git call up their Git and get any *new commits* from them.  Then your Git updates your remote-tracking names so that they match theirs.

    The remote-tracking name is built by sticking the *remote* name (in this case `origin`) in front of their *branch* name, with a slash to keep them apart.  That's why your `origin/master` "tracks" their `master`, updated every time you run `git fetch origin`.<sup>2</sup>

  All these names work similarly.  They all have long forms: `refs/heads/master` is the full spelling of `master`, for instance, vs `refs/remotes/origin/master` for `origin/master`.  That's how Git knows which one is which kind of name.  Git normally then *shortens* the name for display to you, taking off the `refs/heads/` part for branch names, or the `refs/remotes/` part for remote-tracking names.

Note that `git fetch` is as close as there is to the opposite of `git push`.  It might seem like these should be `push` and `pull`, but due to a historical accident<sup>3</sup> it's `push` and `fetch`.  Pull just means: *Run fetch, then run a second Git command, `git merge` by default, to merge with the current branch's upstream.*

Fetch and push are very similar, but with two key differences:

1. Fetch *gets* things.  You tell your Git: *call up the Git whose URL you have stored under the name `origin`* (or whatever remote name you use here).  Your Git calls up a server at that URL, which must answer as a Git repository.  That server then tells you about its branch names and their commits, and your Git checks to see if you have those commits.  If not, your Git asks their Git for those commits, and their parent commits if you don't have them, and the parents' parents if needed, and so on.  They give you all the commits they have, that you don't, that your Git needs to complete these.

   Having gotten the commits, `git fetch` then updates your *remote-tracking names* by renaming their branches.
2. Push *sends* things.  As before, you have your Git call up another Git, by a remote name like `origin`.  Then your Git gives them commits, rather than getting commits from them.  But here, things are slightly different:

   - The commit(s) your Git offers are the *tip commits* of any branches you are pushing.  (If you are just pushing one branch, that's just one commit.)  If they don't have those commits, your Git must offer the parents of these tip commits.  (Most commits have just one parent, so that's one more commit.)  If they don't have *those*, your Git must offer more parents, and so on.  Through this process, your Git finds all the commits their Git needs to have a complete picture of the *tip* commit you're sending: all of its history.

     When you were fetching, they offered *all* their branches.  The difference: you're only pushing whichever branches you specified.
   - After your Git has sent any commits you have, that they don't, that they need to complete the tip commit(s) for the branch(es) you're pushing, your Git sends a polite request for them to set their *branch* name(s).

     When you were fetching, your Git set your *remote-tracking names*.  You're now asking them to set their *branch* names.

To summarize these key points:

- fetch *gets* (all, by default, unless you limit it) commits and branches from them and renames their branches to your remote-tracking names
- push *sends* (one, by default)<sup>4</sup> branch-tip commit (and its ancestors if/as needed) and then asks them to set their branch name(s)

You *can* have `git push` ask them to set a *different* name than the one you use to select the commit(s) to send.  For instance:

```
git push origin test-xyz:new-feature
```

sends the tip commit of your `test-xyz` branch (and its parents and other ancestors if/as needed), but asks them to set or create *their* branch name `new-feature`.

So:

> ... it seems that if any branch_A is tracking a remote branch_B, any pushes will go to branch_B ...

This is entirely wrong, at least by default.  (There is a setting for `push.default` that *does* make that happen, though.)

There is a lot more to know here, in particular, what this `git rev-list --left-right --count` is doing and what it means for commits to be "on"—or more precisely, *reachable from*—a branch name, but I've kind of run out of time and space in this answer, at this point.

---

<sup>1</sup>In particular, files can be *tracked* or *untracked*, some names are *remote-tracking names*, and a branch with an upstream set is said to be *tracking* its upstream.  The verb (in its present participle form) becomes an adjective, modifying *name* or *file*, in the first two cases.

<sup>2</sup>There are ways to run a limited `git fetch` that *doesn't* update all your remote-tracking names.  Using `git pull` sometimes does this, for instance.  I prefer to separate my `git fetch` and my other commands, rather than using the `git pull` fetch-then-run-another-Git-command command.

<sup>3</sup>It's common after fetching to want to *integrate what you fetched*, so at first, `git fetch` was a back-end "plumbing" command, not meant for users to run, and `git pull` ran `git fetch`, then `git merge`.  This was before *remotes* existed as a concept, and hence before remote-tracking names existed either, so there wasn't any reason for users to run `git fetch`.

Over time, Git grew remotes and remote-tracking names, and now the difference between `pull`—fetch and combine—and just `fetch` without combining (or at least, without doing it *yet*) became both useful and important.  But the *name* `pull` was already in use to mean *fetch and combine*, hence this particular historical accident.

<sup>4</sup>That is, this is the default in Git 2.0 and later.  You can change it with `push.default`, and Git versions older than 2.0 default to `matching`.

When using `matching`, your Git asks their Git about their branch names, matches up your matching branch names, and defaults to pushing from your matching names to their matching names.

If you change this setting to `upstream`, your Git asks their Git to set their branch based on the upstream setting of your branch, which is what you were assuming in your question.

The modern default setting is `simple`, which requires that the upstream be set to a branch of the *same name*, so that `git push` on your end just fails right away if your upstream is set to a different name of their side.  However, you can override this easily by typing in `git push origin branch`, which means the same thing as `git push origin branch:branch`: ask their Git to use the same branch name as you are using in your Git.

Comment: Wow, fantastic!  Thanks.  Yea, I think I was thinking of the word 'tracking' incorrectly, or rather I thought it meant more than it does.  I guess I was thinking that tracking meant ~'follow this other branch and merge changes into your current branch'.. but it seems tracking just means `'the single remote branch that you pull from/push to from your local branch'.  Thanks again for this Herculean response.

Comment: @Atom999: well, `git pull` uses the upstream you've set to *do* the `git merge` (or the `git rebase` if you tell it to use rebase instead of merge). So in that sense, it does mean what you are thinking of ... but only to `git pull` itself. If you separate the fetch and the subsequent operation, both `git merge` and `git rebase` use the upstream setting as a default operand: e.g., if the upstream of branch X is origin/X, `git merge` with `X` checked out means `git merge origin/X`.

Comment: Since I like to use the two commands separately, I get more control and more options: I can `git fetch` and then `git merge origin/Y` instead, if I mean to do that.